# Using guard-rspec with factory-girl-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, guard

I'm using [`factory_girl_rails`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails) as a replacement for fixtures in my Rails project. I'm also using [`guard-rspec`](https://github.com/guard/guard-rspec) to automatically run my specs. Guard is not picking up the changes I make to my factory files (e.g. `spec/factories/users.rb`)—I have to stop guard, then reinitialize it for it to pick up those changes.

What are some options for avoiding this manual process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add to your own answer:

I limit what it runs, so it doesn't run too much:

```
watch(%r{^spec/factories/(.+)\.rb$}) { "spec/models" }
```

or including the relevant controller:

```
watch(%r{^spec/factories/(.+)\.rb$}) { |m|
  ["spec/models/", "spec/controllers/#{m[1]}_controller_spec.rb"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After some searching, I stumbled upon [this](https://gist.github.com/aereal/2802359) gist and extracted:

```
watch(%r{^spec/factories/(.+)\.rb$})
```

Which, [according to the documentation](https://github.com/guard/guard#watch), tells the current guard to watch for changes in *.rb files in `spec/factories/`

Answer (score 1):

Limiting even more to the specific specs related to the factory, it should be something like:

```
require 'active_support/inflector'

  watch(%r{^spec/factories/(.+)\.rb$}) do |m|
    %W{
      spec/models/#{m[1].singularize}_spec.rb
      spec/controllers/#{m[1]}_controller_spec.rb
    }
  end
```

Comment: Especially in larger projects, it seems to me like doing `require 'active_support/inflector'` is far worth the payoff since you're really narrowing down what tests to run here.  Awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use this on my macbook, you should add this line in your Guardfile

```
watch(%r{^spec/factories/(.+)\.rb$}) { rspec.spec_dir }
```

and it will automatically run the whole specs file.

If you set the block's return value is 'spec/models', it only run the specs under spec/models dir.

Comment: I think this would be very inefficient.  This would run tons of specs not related to the change in `spec/factories/users.rb`, for example.

Comment: hi @jmera , you are right in a sense. more test more risk-reduce

Comment: If all spec running reduce work efficiency too much, layer based test strategy is a good way to solve this problem, @jmera

Answer (score 0):

I use [`Dir.glob`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Dir.html#method-c-glob) to get a list of all the file names that I want to monitor. This works for nested folder structure as well.

```
require 'active_support/inflector'

watch(%r{^spec/factories/(.+)\.rb$}) { |m|
  [
    *Dir.glob("spec/models/#{m[1].singularize}_spec.rb"),
    *Dir.glob("spec/requests/**/#{m[1]}_spec.rb"),
    *Dir.glob("spec/controllers/**/#{m[1]}_controller_spec.rb"),
  ]
}
```